# Cannot post to the REST API on WSO2 ESB

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-esb

I Created the following REST API on WSO2 Integrator 6.4 with the sequences:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/dsb" name="evCaptureJSONProperties" 
                   xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<resource methods="POST" uri-template="/api/SendSMS">
<inSequence>
  <log description="Entry Confirmation" level="custom">
    <property name="message" value="Request Entered the 
      evCaptureJSONProperties REST API"/>
  </log>
  <payloadFactory media-type="json">
     <format><!-- A json message was here --></format>
     <args/>
  </payloadFactory>
  <respond/>
</inSequence>
<outSequence/>
<faultSequence/>
 </resource>
 </api>
```

And then I posted the request JSON using the following command:

```
Curl -v -X POST --data @evCaptureJSONProperties.json http://localhost:8280/dsb/api/SendSMS --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

But instead of getting back in return the payload an error appeared in the logs and the console:

```
[2018-12-03 10:23:02,432] [EI-Core] ERROR - RelayUtils Error while building 
Passthrough stream
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.synapse.commons.builders.XFormURLEncodedBuilder.
extractParametersFromRequest(XFormURLEncodedBuilder.java:223)
at 
org.apache.synapse.commons.builders.XFormURLEncodedBuilder.
processDocumentWrapper(XFormURLEncodedBuilder.java:128)
at org.apache.synapse.commons.builders.XFormURLEncodedBuilder.
processDocument(XFormURLEncodedBuilder.java:52)
```

I humbly request for some assistance. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the message you are sending. Can you maybe show the contents of your json file that you send to the API?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is the JSON message that I had posted to the API:                                             {
 "Destination": "0112234567",
 "Message": "SMS message",
        "TransactionID": "CO-9999991"
}

Comment: Did you try with this? `curl -X POST http://localhost:8280/dsb/api/SendSMS -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{ "Destination": "0112234567", "Message": "SMS message", "TransactionID": "CO-9999991" } '` or you need to read data from a file via curl command?

Comment: Hi I have tried the curl command you have suggested. I returns another error:curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Destination
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 0112234567,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Message
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: SMS message,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: TransactionID
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: CO-9999991
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1  I am using WIndows.

Comment: Is curl working on windows? :)

Comment: In some cases, yes. I have managed to post and get results from APIs.